# Using Tensorflow Object Detection API: RPN losses keep increasing. Are there ways to make RPN losses decrease?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API for fine-tuning, using my own data. The goal is to detect 2 classes of objects. I am using the pre-trained `faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco` model.

The various detection box precision and recall measures are generally increasing (see screenshots below) and are fairly high:

[image]

[image]

The box classifier losses are decreasing. **HOWEVER,** **the RPN losses are increasing (see screenshots below)** -- It looks that the model is having a hard time distinguishing foregrounds from backgrounds (hence, the increasing RPN losses), but once the model is able to identify and locate the right foreground, it classifies well (hence, the decreasing box classifier losses)? I think this can be observed in the model's performance on test images: the false positive rate (on images that do not contain any of the two classes of target objects) is rather high. On the other hand, on images that do contain those target objects, the model does a fantastic job in accurately identifying and locating those objects.

[image]

**So my question is essentially: what are some of the things I could try to help make sure RPN losses are also decreasing.**

Comment: I've experienced something similar. It is quite strange that `total_loss` keeps increasing (which is validation loss, suggesting possible overfitting) while precision and recall measures keep improving. So my experience is to make sure the validation dataset is correct. For example, the validation dataset should be a random sample of the whole dataset and make sure validation dataset labels are always present.  One possible case is that model predicts a correct region proposal but the groundtruth label doesn't exist.

Comment: I checked my validation dataset, and can confirm that it does in fact include all the categories that exist in the train dataset -- although it is the case that two of the three categories are rather small in numbers (i.e., imbalanced dataset). Not sure if this plays a role

Comment: Did you figure out a way to improve this? I am facing a similar issue where RPN losses are the culprit behind increasing total losses.